# REST GET wcf url not working and 404 error

Tags: vb.net, wcf, rest, wsdl

I am trying to make a rest service and test it. Following is the resulted wsdl file, but I am not able to get the GetData method work.

My WSDL file from `http://localhost:21611/Service1.svc?wsdl`is a working url.

WebConfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData= "c:\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>  
   </system.diagnostics>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
       <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
                    maxMessagesToLog="3000" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
    </diagnostics>
    <bindings />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="test.Service1">
        <endpoint address="Service1.svc" behaviorConfiguration="myRestBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" name="epname" contract="test.IService1" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:21611" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myRestBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetBinding="webHttpBinding" httpGetBindingConfiguration="" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <handlers>
            <remove name="svc-Integrated-4.0" />
            <add name="svc-Integrated-4.0" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

WCF service files:

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IService1

    <OperationContract()>
    <WebGet>
    Function GetData() As String


End Interface

Public Class Service1
    Implements IService1

    Public Function GetData() As String Implements IService1.GetData
        Return "Welcome"
    End Function
End Class
```

I tried with urls like but could not get any result, could you please educate me on this.

```
http://localhost:21611/Service1.svc?wsdl
http://localhost:21611/Service1.svc?wsdl/GetData
http://localhost:21611/Service1.svc?wsdl/GetData/
http://localhost:21611/Service1.svc/GetData
http://localhost:21611/Service1.svc/GetData/
```

Also, I receive 404 error when i try: `http://localhost:21611/Service1.svc/GetData`

Comment: REST services don't use WSDLs.  You might need to specify the URI in the `WebGet` attribute.

Comment: tired with that too as UriTemplate:='GetData' but still did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to complicate your web.config by specifying too many things. Look at the below web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="All" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="SampleRestService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="serviceWebConfiguration">
        <endpoint address="myService" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingName="defaultRest" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="SampleRestService.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="defaultRest"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="64" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="json">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceWebConfiguration">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I have my address attribute set to "myService". So when i use the above config and run the project:

`localhost:52164/Service1.svc` : Shows me the default WCF service page

`localhost:52164/Service1.svc?wsdl` : Shows me the wsdl for the WCF service hosted

`locahost:52164/Service1.svc/myService/getdata` : When used in the browser calls my method GetData (RESTfully) and returns an XML response shown in the browser as below

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Welcome</string>
```

NOTE:

1. The links contain port number 52164 as I am using that port when running the project from visualstudio, so should not make any difference if you replace the port number with 21611 which you are using.
2. My projects namespace is SampleRestService which you would need to replace using "test" when using the above web.config
3. Hope you have a .svc file in your project?

Comment: Literally, a small thing messed my entire 3-4 weeks of time and got frustrated.  The difference is, url should be like "http://localhost:21611/Service1.svc/Service1.svc/getdata/" and not "http://localhost:21611/Service1.svc/getdata/" as per my config file. From your information I came to know that.  This is simple but extremely rare to find information.  Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The best aspect of using RESTful services is having friendly URL where they clearly tell the operation behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not specified the **base address**  in the  web.config

```
<host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:21611" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```

if you don't want to do that then the address should be fully qualified like

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:21611/Service1.svc."  behaviorConfiguration="myRestBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
          name="epname" contract="test.IService1" />
```

Defining address in endpoint the  first **two section(protocol + root address)** are mandatory while the third section is optional. You only specified the optional section.

Comment: I added the base addresses as said above, the result is still the same, not working.  I also downloaded the sample code from codeproject and even it has the same error.  This is freaking me since 1 week. :(

Comment: @surpavan If you hosting your services in iis, then IIS will determine your addressing scheme and you can completely remove the baseAddess section and remove the address section in the endpoint definition.
Remove those, sure it will work...(iis will run on a dynamic port)

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already, I suggest you enable WCF tracing on the service, so you have a better understanding of the service startup, endpoint definitions and any errors.

The following image shows a startup sequence that listens on two endpoints with no errors:

[image]

For reference: WCF tracing provides diagnostic data for fault monitoring and analysis. You can use tracing instead of a debugger to understand how an application is behaving on startup, including the interface endpoints that are listening and any errors.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: "<add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData= "c:\Traces.svclog" />"  I added that file name for listener, but that file is also not created :(.  A simple REST is making my restless form past 3 weeks, even the code downloaded from codeproject results in same output.  PLEASE HELP.

Comment: In order to get tracing to work you need to:  1.) add the source/listener via- <configuration> \ <system.diagnostics> \ <sources> \ <source ... and <listeners ... elements ; 2.) add the wcf diagnostic section like - <system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics >
      <messageLogging 
           logEntireMessage="true" 
           logMalformedMessages="true"
           logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
           logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"

     The following link may provide a better reference:
     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, I have done that, updated the webconfig file in question, still no log file created :(

Comment: You may want to make sure that the IIS, ASP.NET, WCF, and the WCF activation component are correctly installed and registered.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is not how stackoverflow works, but need help, if you would please download the project froom this link and let me know of the issue which I am facing from 3+weeks would be of great help.  Linnk: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D358D316FA2C3A37!3605&authkey=!AJFSNUgScdPqokI&ithint=file%2czip